# Google Cloud Storage return status 404 Not Found even though object exists?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a script that uploads a photo to google compute engine to be processed, saves it in google cloud storage, and then responds with the path which i send to an app engine app to be read... testing with the gsutil cp command shows that the picture is saved correctly to GCS as the cp command always finds it.

However a lot of times app engine has problems find the photo when I send the path, returning a:

NotFoundError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 404

Any thoughts?

Comment: A lot of times? Language? Did you set RetryParams?

Comment: only exceptions to retry again, how do you set retry Params, I'm not using the json api but the google storage library, this is what the code looks like: gcs_file = gcs.open(str(ss.h_photo))
    x = gcs_file.read() 
    gcs_file.close()

Comment: In Python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class

Comment: By the way. I do not fully understand your code. The str() and what about the bucket. Here is mine if you use Python and App Engine: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133

Comment: Awesome thank you that solved it, the str was just to ensure that I'm passing the path as a string... and yet it does contain the bucket.

Comment: @voscausa, since your comments have solved the issue, would you mind writing them up as an answer?

Comment: @Misha. user1368891 has already created an answer for his own question. Or?

Comment: @voscausa right, but it would be more appropriate for _you_ to do that, so that you get the credit for your contribution. Anyway, it's up to you and the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Voscausa, you can simply solve the issue by utilizing adequate parameters:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class